# CSS flexbox "align-items: flex-end;" not working for images

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a header, that can either have a button (image) or a text-label on the right- & left-hand side of the title:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="headerContent">
        <div id="btnLeft"><img src="myimage.png" height="30"></div>
        <div id="title" class="button">HeaderTitle</div>
        <div id="btnRight" class="headerBtn button">RightButton</div>
    </div>
</div><!-- header -->
```

Therefore I'm using CSS flexbox model on the headerContent DIV:

```
#headerContent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Unfortunately the CSS property `align-items: flex-end;` is only working correctly for the text, but NOT for the image. The image always has a small offset so it overflows the top of the header DIV.
It feels like I'm just overseeing something tiny but I can't figure out how it could work...
Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Comment: add to headerContent align-items: stretch;

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/UThjs/1/)**

give height to `#btnLeft`

```
#btnLeft {
    height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to give it a fixed height, because I want it to optionally hold a text label which has a height of 20px... (see [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fK4dd/))